# Is there anyway to create sitemap manually for Shopify Website?

Tags: xml, shopify, sitemap

I recently designed a Shopify website and set it up with Google Search console. Now even though it is showing on Google search when I type it's name out but the structure is not right. I have read over the internet that sitemap.xml file determines this but I am not sure Shopify allows us to create that.

Is there any way around it?

I have tried to look for an answer of Shopify community but didn't find any. I also didn't find any app for this purpose. Do we have to create this file ourselves and upload it as assest or something?

Comment: One way to do this would be write a custom plugin that generates sitemaps whenever an update is made to your store. You can upload the generated sitemap to shopify files, make sure older file is overwritten and preferably archived as well, and submit this link to google search console.

Comment: Thanks but where do I find the existing XML file? I have tried to look for it using Edit Code but can't seem to find it. Or is it due to my premium plan? I know that Shopify Plus users get some extra files like checkout.liquid etc. Is this included in some other Shopify plan?